# setOnClickListener closes Android Application

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm learning now Java with a book "Learning Java by building Android Games" from Packt Publishers by John Horton. I'm really newbie to OOP and I have learned C for one year. I do everything as it is in the book. After I have added setOnClickListener and tried to test my App, I see "the application was closed" instead running new Activity. 
Could you please help me to find out what is wrong? The book is a little bit out of a date (Jan 2015) and I had to correct some initial code to make initial errors disappear.

```
package com.packtpub.mathgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.util.Log;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() Restoring previous state");
            /* restore state */
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() No saved state available");
            /* initialize app */
        }

        final Button buttonPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

===============

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />
```

Comment: Please post your crash log which you can see in the Android Monitor tab at the bottom in Android Studio

Comment: post log and gradle dependencies if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to register the GameActivity In you AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<activity
   android:name=".GameActivity" />
```

inside the application tag

Just a note if these views arn't available your layout will look very wierd ;)

```
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
```

Comment: Many thanks! It works now! It was so easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you register `GameActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file ?

Answer (score 0):

You should getId of your button onClick method only thn you can identity on which button you have click on , now you one

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonPlay:
            //write your implementation here
            Toast.makeText(this, "dsfdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonPlay1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "sdsdsdsd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

**change this:**

```
    final Button buttonPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i;
    i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**in this:**

```
final Button buttonPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i;
            i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: that is exactly the same because he implements the view onclicklistener on his activity

Comment: And you need to pass `MainActivity.this` to the intent not just `this`, because then you will pass the `onClickListener` instead of the `Activity` (this would cause another error when pressing the button)

Comment: Thank you, good to know! I worked always in this way! One never sto to learn :)